# Problem with metrics-server and hpa delays

Tags: kubernetes, delay, flags, hpa, metrics-server

I have an app with 12 containers in one pod, on gke..
I'm trying to improve my app using hpa and i'm stressing it with jmeter!!

The problem is that because of delays(metrics-server and hpa delay) hpa creates new pods but with a delay so doesn't help very much my app... Many of requests are lost and the application is not as fast as I expected..

Any idea? Do you know if i can change the flags for these delays?
i tried to change the --metric-resolution flag, but I did not succeed

Thank you!!!

Comment: the point of containers, is to not have more than 2 in the same pod. Why would you have 12 containers in the same pod ? You should have just one per pod...

Comment: yeap i know i know, but i have a project on kubernetes and it is one part of my project! Do you have any idea, how i could make it work better? Thank you for your reply!!